# Sum of related data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails expense tracker for myself. I simply have categories and expenses, and I want to display a sum of the total related expenses on the Categories index view.

Right now a Category has_many :expenses and an Expense belongs_to :category.

What's the best way to go about displaying a sum of the total related expenses on the category page on for instance the "Grocery" line while it's iterating through the list of categories?

I thought this would be a simple thing to find, but I've hit a bit of a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write a method for total expenses in your Category model like follow:

```
def total_expenses
  self.expenses.sum(:amount) # assuming amount is the column holding expenses amount
end
```

access it as

```
category = Category.find(id)
category.total_expenses
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
Category.all.each do |category|
  total = 0
  category.expenses.each {|expense| total += expense }
  @category_expenses[expense.name] = total
end
```

Then iterate through @category_expenses in your view.